# C++ / Qt - Passing self to pthread_create

Tags: c++, qt, pthreads

I am working on a Qt GUI that will handle a single client. I am NOT using the Qt TCP libraries or the Qt thread library. I am creating my own Server class (more or less for the experience/learning).

I wanted to make sure what I am doing with the pthread handler isn't going to come back to haunt me in the future. My question is... **Is it bad practice to pass *this* into the pthread_create function?** Could this cause problems? It seems to work ok but I am always weary about problems lurking when working with threads.

I will be happy to share more code if it is needed. Thanks for taking a look.

**Server.hpp**

```
class Server : public Socket{

public:

....

 TCPSocket *accept() throw(SocketException);
 static void *listen_for_clients(void *);
 void start() throw(SocketException);
 void set_listen() throw(SocketException);

private:
pthread_t listen_thread;

};
```

**Server.cpp**

```
void HandleTCPClient(TCPSocket *sock);

TCPSocket *Server::accept() throw(SocketException)
{
  int new_conn_sd;
  if ( (new_conn_sd = ::accept(socket_descriptor, NULL, 0)) < 0)
    {
      throw SocketException("Server: accept failed", true);
    }

  return new TCPSocket(new_conn_sd);
}

void *Server::listen_for_clients(void *ptr)
{
    Server * p = (Server *)ptr;
    p->set_listen();

    for (;;)
    {
       HandleTCPClient(p->accept());
    }
    return 0;
}

void Server::start() throw(SocketException)
{
    if(pthread_create(&listen_thread, NULL, listen_for_clients, this)) {
        throw SocketException("Server: cannot create listen thread", true);
    }
}

void Server::set_listen() throw(SocketException)
{
  if (listen(socket_descriptor, queue_length) < 0)
    {
      throw SocketException("Server: set listening socket failed", true);
    }
}

void HandleTCPClient(TCPSocket *sock) {
  std::cout << "Handling client ";

  .....

  delete sock;
}
```

Comment: As long as the lifetime of the object is longer than the lifetime of the thread, it's fine.

Comment: And as long as the object has been fully initialized.